# Not getting any (node index.js) response in terminal

Tags: node.js

I cannot execute node index.js with getting a response. Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'private'
client.on('ready', () =>{
  console.log('VarriousGeneratorBot is now Active!')

  let activities = [`Developer: varrious#6514!` ], i = 0;

  setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`-help | ${activities[i++ % 
  activities.length]}`, { type: "Helping" }), 15000)

});


client.on('message', message =>{

   if (message.content ==='-types'){

      message.author.send('I can Generate --> Netflix | Hulu 
            | Minecraft | Disney+ | Origin | Roblox | NordVPN | Steam <-- ')};

   });

client.on('message', message =>{

if (message.content ==='-help'){

message.author.send(' -commands , -stock , -gen (account), -help(this), -types ')

};

client.on('message', message =>{
   if (!message.guild) return;
   if (message.content =='-gen NordVPN'){

      var string = `private`;
      var words = string.split('\n');
      let random = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
      message.author.send(`${random}`);{
      };
   };

});

client.login(token)});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats happen because you put `client.login()` in message trigger block.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'private'
client.on('ready', () =>{
  console.log('VarriousGeneratorBot is now Active!')

  let activities = [`Developer: varrious#6514!` ], i = 0;

  setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`-help | ${activities[i++ % 
  activities.length]}`, { type: "Helping" }), 15000)

});

client.on('message', message =>{
   if (!message.guild) return;
   if (message.content =='-gen NordVPN'){

      var string = `private`;
      var words = string.split('\n');
      let random = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
        message.author.send(`${random}`);{
      };
   };

});

client.login(token);
```